How to emulate a momentary push button with a SPST slide switch
My situation:
A power button (non-latching, 6 pins, but only 3 connected) on a board. When pressed, this button first bridges pins 1 and 2, then pins 2 and 3 and then returns to its original position.
Pin 1 is connected to GND via 10k, pin 2 is 5V and pin 3 is connected to GND via 10k and to signal.
Now I wanted to emulate the pushbutton (which I now have desoldered) with a slide switch with 2 pins (ON/OFF) and had tried the instructions from ChatGPT with transistors (2N2222) and capacitors, but that didn't work.
Can someone here show me a small circuit, or what do I have to do to realise my switch?
Here is the guide ChatGPT wrote (doesn't make sense or does it?):
https://pastebin.com/raw/54JKe5kN
EDIT: Could I realize it with an ATTiny85?

" this button first bridges pins 1 and 2, then pins 2 and 3 and then returns to its original position" That doesn't sound like a SPST then, because you have several positions, if I understand you correctly? Or is it a 1/0/1 switch with two directions? A picture would be quite helpful here. As would a simple schematic.

Like I said, I'm kind of clueless, so I can't give any schematics.
But I didn't say the original button was SPST., the one I want to use is a SPST slide switch.

Aah, sorry I misunderstood you. So it seems you only need a 10k pull-down to ground on the side where the signal is attached and 5V on the other side and there you go, I guess?

Yes, exactly. Pin 1 (just 10k to GND) and Pin 2 (5V) and then Pin 2 (5v) and Pin 3 (10k to GND and signal) to power on the device.

There's no obvious need for a transistor here if the target expects 5V. If what you are switching is power I don't see what good a pull-down resistor is either. As for ChatGPT, it is a chat bot for amusement purposes, it doesn't know anything about electronics or anything else and as such talks nonsense more often than not.

are any pins bridged when the power button is not pressed?

No, they are not.

Please, stop asking ChatGPT about technical engineering questions. Unless you know the subject well enough to quality check the output of the text generator, the answer is worse than no answer. It is extremely good at "sounding" convincing, but it does not "know" anything and the answer might be wildly wrong and you are none the wiser. Ergo worse off than when you knew you didn't know anything!

Noticed that now. ;)

You can replace push-button with Spst according schematic:

Edit:
For pin3 be delayed a little after pin1 use this schematic:

So for pin1 use first schematic and for pin3 use second one. Both are feed from one Spst (right pin).
Edit 2:
To make it more professional with switch bounce filtering and sharpening/squaring the output edges use this:


Thanks, but what's with pin 3? Is it the bottom right line?

The bottom line is Gnd. For pin3 it depends if it needs to be delayed after pin1. If not just use two of this circuits. If yes you need to make a delay with transistors.

Two of this circuit with one SPST?

Yes. Both circuits connect to right side of Spst.

Like I said: Pin 1 + 2, then 2 + 3 and then there shouldn't be any voltage on 1 and 3. But with a single SPST switch this wouldn't work?

Sure. The series capacitor passes the voltage to pins 1&3 just temporary (like 100ms), then goes off. But as I sad if you use just two of this circuits the pins 1&3 are feed simultaneously (without pin3 delayed). To get a pin3 delayed use circuit I added to Edits.

Thanks! Would have tested it, but unfortunately I don't have any P-Channel MOSFETs at hand. Not possible with out it I think?

You could use a Pnp transistors instead, but you need to add a base resistors to them. Also the output edges will not be so nice without adding some circuitry.

How would I do it with a transistor?
